# Remove a sub heading text under products page title in OceanWP theme

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I am trying to figure out how to change/remove the text under "Products (Varer)" on my Wordpress woocommerce website like in this screenshot:

[image: See this picture for reference.]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Might be a weird question: But what does that say if you translate it to English, might be a little easier to find it that way.

Comment: Yeah knew it was a problem with the danish. The thing i have circled around translated is ''Here you can add new items to your webshop''.

Comment: Which theme are you using in Wordpress?

Comment: I'm using OceanWP, but it's not up to date. Started changing the functions.php without using a child theme, so i'm waiting on updating until i've set that up.

Comment: Easiest fix would be to get the class / id of the element and add `display: none` to additional css within Wordpress and then just edit the text if you find out where you can change it.

Comment: Try: in the customizer -> oceanwp settings -> title -> dispay heading turn that off

Comment: Can't seem to find that. Can that be because it's not under a oceanwp site, but under a woocommerce created site: www.pagename.xxx/shop ?

Comment: Hold up, let me set this up locally. Meanwhile adding this to your extra css should get rid of it until you find the proper way to do it: `.clr .page-subheading {display: none}`

Comment: Check my answer below.

Comment: I'm adding that as you can see here https://i.imgur.com/SmgikOu.jpg

Comment: But still nothing changes https://i.imgur.com/rHoTSyc.jpg

Comment: That's my bad, I forgot to add the dots to the classname, fixed now!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to OceanWP's docs, you can add this function to your `functions.php` file of the child theme to remove the subheading:

```
// Remove the Shop page subheading
function my_remove_shop_page_header_subheading( $subheading ) {

    if ( is_shop() ) {
        $subheading = false;
    }

    // Return the subheading
    return $subheading;

}
add_filter( 'ocean_post_subheading', 'my_remove_shop_page_header_subheading' );
```

Alternatively, you can add one line of extra css to your website (tested and worked):

```
.clr .page-subheading {display: none}
```

Comment: Hello team -- thanks for sharing this. It worked for me. It is worth mentioning that if you don't have OceanWP child theme, then you need to get it first, install it, export/import the settings from the master theme to the child theme, then make the above edits into the child theme.

Best wishes,
Bogdan Ciocoiu
www.b2bconsult.co.uk

Answer (score 0):

Follow this steps to edit/remove sub heading.

1. Go to Pages > select shop page > Edit.
2. Under Ocean WP settings choose Title.
3. Enter your desired subheading or a single space in case you want to remove that altogether.

Note: A single space would remove that line altogether, won't create an empty line as of now.

I am not sure if that would change with theme/plugin updates, but is a good option if you have not created child theme. In case you have created a child theme have a look here: https://docs.oceanwp.org/article/500-remove-the-shop-page-subheading